# Can not seem to pull out the attributes of this object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, rubymine

I have a method where an object is called but I can not seem to pull out the attributes of this object and I do not understand why.

```
    def set_cashier
      test = User.first
      result = test.login
      Rails.logger.debug "User is: #{result}"
```

as I set a breakpoint on the second line in rubymine IDE (I can see the following)

```
    def set_cashier
      test = User.first   test: #<User:0x00000004809ea0>
      result = test.login    result: nil  test: #<User:0x00000004809ea0>
      Rails.logger.debug "User is: #{result}"
```

I know I have attributes on this object like `id` and `login`. When I run the debugger in my IDE I can see `@attributes = Hash(17 elements)` and I can see them listed inside as `'id' = "433"` and `'login' = "firstname.lastname"` etc...in the rubymine debugger it looks sort of like this...

```
result = nil
test = {User}#<User:0x00000004809ea0>
    @attributes = Hash(17 elements)
       'id' = "433"
       'login' = "firstname.lastname"
      ...
```

How do I return the value of 'login'?

test = User.first seems to give an object that I can see in the debugger Variables tab that I can open and see a value for "@attributes = Hash(17 elements)" and I can see those values inside there....and yet...

"result = test.login" gives a nil result which so confusing

I would think that "test = User.first.login" should work ...

```
    def set_cashier
      test = User.first.login
      result = test
      Rails.logger.debug "User.first is: #{result}"
```

but this gives the same error ...so confusing.

(the full error displayed in the browser looks like so...)

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.map
```

I've been at this for a few days now. If this question does not make sense please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

---

UPDATED:

Per request of a commenter I'm including the code for the User model
(By the way...I inherited this code...so nothing in this file was written by me)

Note:
Rails 3.1 (updated from a rails 2.x app)
ruby 1.9.3p551

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_userstamp
  has_and_belongs_to_many "roles"

  # Virtual attribute for the unencrypted password
  attr_accessor :password

  validates_presence_of     :login, :email
  validates_presence_of     :password,                   :if => :password_required?
  validates_presence_of     :password_confirmation,      :if => :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :password, :within => 4..40, :if => :password_required?, :allow_nil => true
  validates_confirmation_of :password,                   :if => :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :login,    :within => 3..40, :allow_nil => true
  validates_length_of       :email,    :within => 3..100, :allow_nil => true
  validates_uniqueness_of   :login, :email, :case_sensitive => false
  validates_uniqueness_of   :cashier_code, :if => :cashier_code
  validates_format_of       :login, :with => /[^0-9]/, :message => "must contain a non-numeric character"
  before_save :encrypt_password
  before_save :add_cashier_code
  before_save :disable_reason_cannot_login_on_reenable

  def disable_reason_cannot_login_on_reenable
    return unless self.can_login && self.can_login_changed?
    self.reason_cannot_login = "" if self.reason_cannot_login && self.reason_cannot_login.length > 0
  end

  belongs_to :contact
  has_one :skedjulnator_access

  ####################################################
  # I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT THIS IS HERE FOR, BUT IF YOU #
  # FORGET ABOUT IT YOU WILL SPEND AN HOUR TRYING TO #
  # FIGURE OUT WHAT YOU DID WRONG                    #
  ####################################################
  # prevents a user from submitting a crafted form that bypasses activation
  # anything else you want your user to change should be added here.
  attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :can_login, :shared

  scope :can_login, {:conditions => ["can_login = 't'"]}

  def self.hidden_columns
    super + [:crypted_password, :salt]
  end

  def can_view_disciplinary_information?
    !! (self.contact and self.contact.worker and self.contact.worker.worker_type_today and self.contact.worker.worker_type_today.name != 'inactive')
  end

  def update_skedjulnator_access_time
    self.skedjulnator_access ||= SkedjulnatorAccess.new
    self.skedjulnator_access.user_id_will_change!
    self.skedjulnator_access.save!
  end

  def grantable_roles
    self.roles.include?(Role.find_by_name('ADMIN')) ? Role.find(:all) : self.roles
  end

  def to_s
    login
  end

  def self.reset_all_cashier_codes
    self.find(:all).each{|x|
      x.reset_cashier_code
      x.save
    }
  end

  def contact_display_name
    self.contact ? self.contact.display_name : self.login
  end

  def add_cashier_code
    reset_cashier_code if !self.shared and cashier_code.nil?
  end

  def reset_cashier_code
    valid_codes = (1000..9999).to_a - User.find(:all).collect{|x| x.cashier_code}
    my_code = valid_codes[rand(valid_codes.length)]
    self.cashier_code = my_code
  end

  def merge_in(other)
    for i in [:actions, :donations, :sales, :types, :users, :volunteer_tasks, :contacts, :gizmo_returns]
      User.connection.execute("UPDATE #{i.to_s} SET created_by = #{self.id} WHERE created_by = #{other.id}")
      User.connection.execute("UPDATE #{i.to_s} SET updated_by = #{self.id} WHERE updated_by = #{other.id}")
    end
    ["donations", "sales", "volunteer_tasks", "disbursements", "recyclings", "contacts"].each{|x|
      User.connection.execute("UPDATE #{x.to_s} SET cashier_created_by = #{self.id} WHERE cashier_created_by = #{other.id}")
      User.connection.execute("UPDATE #{x.to_s} SET cashier_updated_by = #{self.id} WHERE cashier_updated_by = #{other.id}")
    }
    self.roles = (self.roles + other.roles).uniq
    self.save!
  end

  # Authenticates a user by their login name and unencrypted password.  Returns the user or nil.
  def self.authenticate(login, password)
    if login.to_i.to_s == login
      u = find_by_contact_id(login.to_i)
    else
      u = find_by_login(login) # need to get the salt
    end
    return u if u && u.can_login && u.authenticated?(password)
    return nil
  end

  # Encrypts some data with the salt.
  def self.encrypt(password, salt)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--#{salt}--#{password}--")
  end

  # Encrypts the password with the user salt
  def encrypt(password)
    self.class.encrypt(password, salt)
  end

  def authenticated?(password)
    crypted_password == encrypt(password)
  end

  def remember_token?
    remember_token_expires_at && Time.now.utc < remember_token_expires_at
  end

  # These create and unset the fields required for remembering users between browser closes
  def remember_me
    remember_me_for 2.weeks
  end

  def remember_me_for(time)
    remember_me_until time.from_now.utc
  end

  def remember_me_until(time)
    self.remember_token_expires_at = time
    self.remember_token            = encrypt("#{email}--#{remember_token_expires_at}")
    save(false)
  end

  def forget_me
    self.remember_token_expires_at = nil
    self.remember_token            = nil
    save(false)
  end

  # start auth junk

  def User.current_user
    Thread.current['user'] || User.fake_new
  end

  attr_accessor :fake_logged_in

  def User.fake_new
    u = User.new
    u.fake_logged_in = true
    u
  end

  def logged_in
    ! fake_logged_in
  end

  def to_privileges
    return "logged_in" if self.logged_in
  end

  def privileges
    @privileges ||= _privileges
  end

  def _privileges
    olda = []
    return olda if !self.can_login
    a = [self, self.contact, self.contact ? self.contact.worker : nil, self.roles].flatten.select{|x| !x.nil?}.map{|x| x.to_privileges}.flatten.select{|x| !x.nil?}.map{|x| Privilege.by_name(x)}
    while olda != a
      a = a.select{|x| !x.restrict} if self.shared
      olda = a.dup
      a << olda.map{|x| x.children}.flatten
      a = a.flatten.sort_by(&:name).uniq
      a = a.select{|x| !x.restrict} if self.shared
    end
    a = a.map{|x| x.name}
    a
  end

  def has_privileges(*privs)
    positive_privs = []
    negative_privs = []
    privs.flatten!
    for i in privs
      if i.match(/^!/)
        negative_privs << i.sub(/^!/, "")
      else
        positive_privs << i
      end
    end
    if positive_privs.length > 0
      positive_privs << "role_admin"
    end
    if negative_privs.length > 0
      negative_privs << "role_admin"
    end
    my_privs = self.privileges
    #puts "NEG: #{negative_privs.inspect}, POS: #{positive_privs.inspect}, MY: #{my_privs.inspect}"
    return (negative_privs & my_privs).length == 0 && ((positive_privs & my_privs).length > 0 || positive_privs.length == 0)
  end

  # end auth junk

  protected
  # before filter
  def encrypt_password
    return if password.blank?
    self.salt = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--#{Time.now.to_s}--#{login}--") if new_record?
    self.crypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def password_required?
    crypted_password.blank? || !password.blank?
  end

end
```

Eliminating the IDE as source of problem:

So I ran Rails console and got the following error...

```
irb(main):001:0> User.first
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  SHOW search_path
  User Indexes (1.1ms)   SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid
 FROM pg_class t
 INNER JOIN pg_index d ON t.oid = d.indrelid
 INNER JOIN pg_class i ON d.indexrelid = i.oid
 WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
 AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND t.relname = 'users'
 AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname IN ('"$user"','public') )
 ORDER BY i.relname

  User Indexes (0.4ms)   SELECT c2.relname, i.indisunique, pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid, 0, true)
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c, pg_catalog.pg_class c2, pg_catalog.pg_index i
 WHERE c.relname = 'users'
 AND c.oid = i.indrelid AND i.indexrelid = c2.oid
 AND i.indisprimary = 'f'
 AND i.indexprs IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY 1

(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>
irb(main):002:0>
```

...very confusing

Comment: Can you add the definition of `User` to your question? Do you get the same error for any attribute or just `login`? I guess the other thing to try is running `rails console` and see if you have the same problem (i.e., rule out an issue with your IDE).

Comment: is `User` a Rails model? has it been saved to the DB before you run `set_cashier`?

Comment: @rmlockerd updated my post with the code for the User model. Yes, the same error for any other attributes. Also ran user.first in rails console...posted output in "updated" section on post.

Comment: You issue is almost certainly that the model defines `attr_accessors` over the top of your ActiveRecord attributes. I don't think I ever used Rails 2, so maybe that did something in the day, but in later versions of Rails that will create a method that returns the value of the instance variable `@login` (or whatever) rather than the actual database attribute. Comment that line out and see how you go.

Comment: @rmlockerd hmm so place line 6 `attr_accessor :password` below...say...line 37 `attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :can_login, :shared` ?

Comment: Sorry, no my comment was incorrect. I mean remove the `attr_accessible` line. That's what is overriding the ActiveRecord getters/setters for your record attributes.

Comment: @rmlockerd Hmm I got back `#to_s method raised exception: you have a nil object ...` I see a def to_s about the 5th method down from `attr_accessible`, not sure if THAT is the to_s that is breaking as I'm setting breakpoints in it but nothing is happening at that point. Hmm.

Comment: @Clara I think I see what you are saying. the method `authorize` is being called before `set_cashier`in the before_filter right above `set_cashier` and authorize calls `current_user()`...I'll dig into that and see what I get. I'll update accordingly.